# Rough grinding noise when braking at low speed

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, silverado, braking, grinding

I have a 2005 chevy silverado 2500hd. When I apply the brakes at a low speed a rough grinding noise comes from the front driver side tire. The harder I push the worse the sound becomes. I put on new brake pads a month ago and the rotors are in good condition. Even with the noise there are no other issues with the braking. I'm not sure why this started happening and cant find anything wrong. Any ideas would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was the noise the reason you changed out the pads in the first place (if not, why were they changed)? Were the rotors resurfaced or replaced when the change occurred? Or did you just put on new pads?

Comment: Hi Paulster, thanks for your question. I changed the pads because the previous ones we're worn out, there was no noise before I changed them. The rotors stayed as they were and were not altered. I simply put on the new pads, and after about a week that one tire/brake is making the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the old disc pads and hope I don't get the noise again. If you do its not the new pads. If you don't its something to do with the new pads.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention having the rotors turned when you replaced the pads.  Even if you can't see or feel them, there will be some groves in the rotor.  This can conceivably cause the sound.

Assuming the rotors were not turned, you should re-do the brake job.  Get the rotors turned AND use new brake pads.

Alternately, if you did not use the lubricate between the backs of the pads and the caliper, it can cause noise.